# "Go to sheet" button/sheets slow down the performance on Tableau Server

Tags: performance, tableau-api

I'm publishing my workbook to Tableau Server. I'm faced to long loading times. I noticed that this is due to the "go to sheet" button or sheets. I published two same sheets, except one with "go to sheet" sheets other one without, and the sheet without "go to sheet" action loads much faster than the other one. Putting buttons instead of sheets doesn't solve the problem. I've searched it on google and I couldn't find any answer. I'd appreciated any help!

Thanks in advance!